How to store the result of a datafram grouping seperatly using Pandas Python
I'm facing a challenge when I'm trying to group a dataframe, here's a fake datafram which similir to the real one :
**univertcity   country     sector  name    firstname   code**
Evergreen College   USA     URO    Isabel   Emily       694123
Evergreen College   USA     URO    Rami     David       63123
Evergreen College   Swiss   URO   Johnson   Parker      114196
Cascade University  CANADA  DIG   Anthony   Jessica     55177
Cascade University  CANADA  VIP   Michael   Thierry     124199
Horizon Institute   FRANCE  MP    Ben       Samuel      25896
Horizon Institute   FRANCE  MP    Benjamin  John        52366

what I'm looking for is to group by univercity col the country and finaly the sector, and I would like (somehow) to fetch each grouping sepratly..because i woulf like to display each grouping using html table..the is what i intend to get :

could you help please ?

Just use groupby:
gp = df.groupby(["univertcity", "country", "sector"])
for key, item in gp:
    print(gp.get_group(key), "\n\n")



hi, it works but I got an error when I execute :grouping.get_group(key).loc[0]["unevercity"], because I need to get the univercity name above each datafram..do you have any solution please

And with grouping.get_group(key).reset_index().loc[0]["univertcity"] ?

Or easier, just replace your loc by iloc.

One possible solution:
groups = df.groupby(['univertcity', 'country', 'sector'])

excel_file = "<your file>"
current_row = 0   

with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer: 
    for name, group in groups:

        key = list(name)
        key_df = pd.DataFrame(key, columns=['Group']) 

        key_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=current_row)
        current_row += len(key_df) +1
       
        group.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=current_row)
        current_row += len(group) +2

